Temperatures OpenHardwareMonitor with python
I want to retrieve the temperatures, RAM memory usage, used disk space, and CPU load from my computer. I'm using OpenHardwareMonitor for this, but I'm able to get everything except the temperature. When I execute OpenHardwareMonitor on my computer, the temperatures are displayed, but I can't retrieve them with Python. Any ideas?
Of all the options I tried, OpenHardwareMonitor was the only one that showed me results.

import clr

file = "OpenHardwareMonitorLib.dll"
clr.AddReference(file)

from OpenHardwareMonitor import Hardware

openhardwaremonitor_sensortypes = [
    "Voltage",      # 0
    "Clock",        # 1
    "Temperature",  # 2
    "Load",         # 3
    "Fan",          # 4
    "Flow",         # 5
    "Control",      # 6
    "Level",        # 7
    "Factor",       # 8
    "Power",        # 9
    "Data",         # 10
    "SmallData",    # 11
]

openhardwaremonitor_hwtypes = {
    Hardware.HardwareType.Mainboard: "Mainboard",
    Hardware.HardwareType.SuperIO: "Super I/O",
    Hardware.HardwareType.CPU: "CPU",
    Hardware.HardwareType.RAM: "RAM",
    Hardware.HardwareType.GpuNvidia: "Nvidia GPU",
    Hardware.HardwareType.GpuAti: "ATI GPU",
    Hardware.HardwareType.TBalancer: "T-Balancer",
    Hardware.HardwareType.Heatmaster: "Heatmaster",
    Hardware.HardwareType.HDD: "HDD",
}

def initialize_openhardwaremonitor():
    handle = Hardware.Computer()
    handle.MainboardEnabled = True
    handle.SuperIOEnabled = True
    handle.CPUEnabled = True
    handle.RAMEnabled = True
    handle.GPUEnabled = True
    handle.HDDEnabled = True
    handle.SSDEnabled = True
    handle.BatteryEnabled = True
    handle.PsuEnabled = True
    handle.CoolingDeviceEnabled = True
    handle.UPSEnabled = True

    handle.Open()
    return handle

def fetch_stats(handle):
    for hardware in handle.Hardware:
        hardware.Update()
        print(f"Hardware: {openhardwaremonitor_hwtypes.get(hardware.HardwareType, 'Unknown')} - {hardware.Name}")
        for sensor in hardware.Sensors:
            parse_sensor(sensor)

        for subhardware in hardware.SubHardware:
            subhardware.Update()
            print(f"  SubHardware: {openhardwaremonitor_hwtypes.get(subhardware.HardwareType, 'Unknown')} - {subhardware.Name}")
            for subsensor in subhardware.Sensors:
                parse_sensor(subsensor)

def parse_sensor(sensor):
    if sensor.Value is not None:
        sensor_type = openhardwaremonitor_sensortypes[sensor.SensorType]
        unit = "\u00B0C" if sensor_type == "Temperature" else ""
        if sensor_type == "Temperature":
            print(
                u"%s %s %s Sensor #%i %s - %.2f%s"
                % (
                    openhardwaremonitor_hwtypes.get(sensor.Hardware.HardwareType, "Unknown"),
                    sensor.Hardware.Name,
                    sensor_type,
                    sensor.Index,
                    sensor.Name,
                    sensor.Value,
                    unit
                )
            )
        else:
            print(
                u"%s %s %s Sensor #%i %s - %.2f"
                % (
                    openhardwaremonitor_hwtypes.get(sensor.Hardware.HardwareType, "Unknown"),
                    sensor.Hardware.Name,
                    sensor_type,
                    sensor.Index,
                    sensor.Name,
                    sensor.Value
                )
            )
    else:
        print(f"Sensor without value: {sensor.Name} of type {openhardwaremonitor_sensortypes[sensor.SensorType]}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("OpenHardwareMonitor:")
    HardwareHandle = initialize_openhardwaremonitor()
    fetch_stats(HardwareHandle)

